# ¿Cómo puedo realizar la conversión de horas en formato de 12 a 24 en php, si la hora que me da de la base de datos es así '01:30:47'?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Tengo la base de datos que me está dando las horas que anteriormente se registraron de esta manera:

**09:04:48**
**01:30:47**

al momento de crear una variable para traerme el registro de la base de datos a php me las traigo como

```
$h1=$va['entrada_mañana']; (que sería las 09:04:48)
$h2=$va['salida_mañana']; (que sería las 01:30:47)
```

pero al momento de querer sacar la diferencia de esas horas hago la resta así

```
$horas_totales=(strtotime($h1)-strtotime($h2));
            $totalWorking=$horas_totales; 
            $timeWorking=gmdate("H:i:s", abs($totalWorking));
echo $timeWorking;
```

me realiza la operación correctamente, pero no como yo quiero. Quiero que me de el tiempo transcurrido entre la *01:30:47* y las *09:04:48* que serían **04:25:59**
sin embargo el resultado que me da es **07:34:01**, que básicamente está correcto pero lo que busco es que más bien se haga la conversión del formato de las 12 horas a 24 para poder restar *09:04:48* - *13:30:47* y así me de el resultado esperado.

Comment: ¿Como sabes que fue a las `01:30:47` PM y no AM? PD: te acabo de dar una pista de como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que en formato 12 horas, al llegar a la 13 las horas se reinician a 1. Para arreglar el problema, con un `if` y algunos ajustes bastará:

```php
$h_tmstp1 = strtotime($h1);
$h_tmstp2 = strtotime($h2);
if($h_tmstp2 < $h_tmstp1) {
    $h_tmstp2 += 12 * 60 * 60; // Agregar 12 horas
}
$horas_totales= $h_tmstp1 - $h_tmstp2;
            $totalWorking=$horas_totales; 
            $timeWorking=gmdate("H:i:s", abs($totalWorking));
echo $timeWorking;
```

**[*] Problema Importante**: Si tienes trabajadores nocturnos, que pasan de las `00:00:00` (12 AM), no habrá manera segura de hacer estos cálculos.

**[*] Solución segura y definitiva**:
Acostúmbrate a [usar estándares](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). Te ahorras todo ese problema utilizando el formato completo de fecha y hora (24).
Fecha_entrada y Fecha_salida --> `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`. Ejemplo: `2022-10-25 14:26:45`

Answer (score 0):

algo que podrías hacer sería emplear con PHP lo siguiente, puedo suponer que esos valores los tomas de PHP y deseas que tu formato de tiempo sea de 24 horas mas no la de 12 horas. Resulta que ello se puede alterar sencillamente colocando el h en date con Mayúscula.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si es el caso de PHP deberías almacenar tus tiempos de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen

```
<?php

$hora_24 = date("H:m:s");

?>
```

Y con MySQL puede instruirte de este enlace

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format